# The meaning of variable "http_connect" of curl

Tags: curl

curl has a variable named "http_connect" when using '-w' option. 
The man page says:

> http_connect The numerical code that was found in the last response
>   (from a proxy) to a curl CONNECT request.

I don't understand what it means and what the variable can be used for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this is only received when you use a HTTP proxy.

When you use a HTTP proxy to connect to a HTTPS site, a client then issues a request to the proxy known as CONNECT. The CONNECT request basically asks the proxy to tunnel through all data to the remote server + port number.

After the CONNECT request is completed successfully, the client can send the *actual* (second) request through that proxy tunnel to the peer server.

The `http_connect` variable is thus a way to get the response code from the CONNECT response (from the proxy), which as you see here is separate from the server's response code. You'd extract the server's response code with `response_code`.

Both those variables return the HTTP response codes from their respective responses (called [status code](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6) in the HTTP standard). That's a number between 100 and 599 that describes "the result of the attempt to understand and satisfy the request"

Comment: Nice explanation!  But I am confused what values could this variable has?

Comment: I extended my answer somewhat to include that too.